# Where can I find a good phrasal verbs dictionary?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

Where can I find a good phrasal verbs dictionary, and can someone help me out? Does anyone have the Cambridge Phrasal Verbs Dictionary or a similar resource they could recommend?